# Why dose it increase more size I thouht

Tags: android

I put two songs in the raw folder.. And "song1.mp3 + song2.mp3" 's sizes are 5MB

But the Android ProjectFolder size become 17.6MB. Not 5MB(Songs Size) + 50KB(project size)

why dose it increase size about three times ,,?? in my opinion, 5.05MB size may be correct..

It is very wasteful.. Help Me !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the project folder? well... just guessing here but... the project folder contains

A the resource
B the compiled resource
C the apk which has everything packed into it :)

soooooo, yea. check how big the bin folder is and don't push that to the repository :) no need

Answer (score 0):

try to put this files in Assets folder.

Sorry, if my answer not useful. I don't do it.

Hope, it help you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your project in SVN/GIT or something similar? Could be the .SVN info that takes up that extra space. When you compile the app I doubt it will be 17MB large.

Comment: Thank you !! ,,, how do I set GIT and check 
whether SVN or GIT ??

Comment: If you don't know if you are using SVN or GIT you probably aren't using anyone of them :)